# SQL query to create function counting total cells with selector

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-function

I am using phpMyAdmin and am trying to create a SQL query that creates a function.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_totalLanguages(_CountryCode CHAR(3)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE totalLang INT;
  SET totalLang = SELECT count(DISTINCT Language) FROM countrylanguage WHERE (CountryCode == _CountryCode);
  RETURN totalLang;
END$$
DELIMITER
```

The table looks like this:

```
+=============+==========+
|    countrylanguage     |
+=============+==========+
| CountryCode | Language |
+=============+==========+
|         USA |   English|
+-------------+----------+
|         USA |   Spanish|
+-------------+----------+
|         USA |    French|
+-------------+----------+
|         MEX |   Spanish|
+-------------+----------+
|         MEX |   English|
+-------------+----------+
|         GER |    German|
+-------------+----------+
|         GER |   English|
+=============+==========+
```

I want to be able to call the function with a countrycode argument. The function would then count how many separate languages exist with that country code, and then return the count as an integer. Currently, this query doesn't give me any errors, but doesn't do anything.

get_totalLanguages('MEX') should return 2.

get_totalLanguages('USA') should return 3.

etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the function call's return value

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION get_totalLanguages(_CountryCode CHAR(3))
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  DECLARE totalLang INT;
  SELECT count(DISTINCT Language) into totalLang FROM countrylanguage WHERE CountryCode = _CountryCode);
  RETURN totalLang;
END$$
DELIMITER
```

`SELECT get_totalLanguages('MEX');`

Comment: hmm, this one gives me an error at CounterCode == _CountryCode

Comment: Have a look at my edit, should not be using a double equal sign for equality in MySQL.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Thanks!